# 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am getting a 405 (Method Not Allowed) in Laravel while trying to delete an item using ajax. Someone please help.

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/destroy', 'PagesController@destroy');
Auth::routes();
```

Here is my ajax code

```
        function confirmDelete(id){
        //alert('Delete post id-'+id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'blogs/destroy',
            data: {'id' : id},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(res){
                console.log("worked");
                    alert(res);
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is my controller

```
public function destroy (Request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    echo json_encode ($id);
//        $blog = Blog::findorFail ( $id );
//        $blog->delete ();
//        return response(['msg'=>'Post deleted', 
'status'=>'success']);
//        return redirect::to ( '/blogs' )->with ( 'success', 'Post 
successfully deleted!' );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because your request URI `/blog/destroy` doesn't match the route definition `/destroy`.

Therefore either change the route to

```php
Route::post('/blog/destroy', 'PagesController@destroy');
```

or change your request

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/destroy',
    // ...
})
```

Comment: This is means that it works now and you have issues with controller code.

Comment: Here is my controller. I can't seem to find any issue with it. Can you

Comment: The 500 error is *another* problem. If the answer above helped you (which it did), it should be upvoted and marked as accepted.

Comment: Voted. Any issue with my controller? Anyone please?

Comment: @ElizabethW.Ng'ang'a Show the exact error message that you get. You should be able to find all details in your log file `\storage\logs\laravel.log`

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out. Please consider accepting the answer. [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/232667)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for routes->
`Route::post('/blog/destroy', 'PagesController@destroy')->(destroyPage);`

Try this inside ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url:'{{ route('destroyPage') }}',
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer just login to my server and disable the ModSecurity and its works, so, later on, I configure the ModSecurity to not get the 405 methods not allowed error on live server.