# Laravel 405 method not allowed on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

The code works just fine on my local dev environment, but gives a `405 method not allowed` exception when I upload it to the server. The solutions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622818/error-405-method-not-allowed-laravel-5) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739378/405-method-not-allowed-laravel) question didn't work for me.

Here's the controller.

```
    public function DeleteMultipleProjects(Request $request){
        $json = $request->projectsToDelete;
        $to_delete = collect([]);

        $projects = json_decode($json);
        foreach ($projects as $project) {
            $to_delete->push($project->id);
        }

        Project::destroy($to_delete);
    }
```

Here's the corresponding entry in the routes file.

```
Route::post('/ajax/dashboard/delete-projects', 'ProjectController@DeleteMultipleProjects');
```

And here's the AJAX call to the URL.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/dashboard/delete-projects',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            projectsToDelete: JSON.stringify(vThis.selectedProjects),
        },
        complete: function(){
            vThis.refreshProjects();
        }
    });
```

This is what the data looks like for an example test case.

```
[{"id":140,"name":"a","updated_at":"Sun, Oct 21, 2018 4:31 AM","selected":true,"selectHovering":false},{"id":139,"name":"New Project","updated_at":"Sun, Oct 21, 2018 4:31 AM","selected":true,"selectHovering":false}]
```

How can I get past this error, and why does this only happen in production?

**Edit** It's worth noting that I have other AJAX calls to routes throughout my application, and they work fine.

Comment: Are the requests going directly to the app server?

Comment: What do you mean? The AJAX requests are going straight to the server, yes. It's worth noting that I have other AJAX calls to routes throughout my application, and they work fine.

Comment: I was clarifying your env. Typically, in enterprise envs, requests are routed through a layered arch.

Comment: Oh yeah, nah, that's not the case here.

Comment: Please post the request info from devtools.

Comment: Do you have your routes file cached on production

Comment: I also doubt your request handler is correct. You shouldn't have to decode anything. Laravel takes care of that for you.

Comment: Are you by chance sending a `_method` field with the request with a value of DELETE, perhaps as a remnant of old, modified code?

Comment: It might be worth including more of your routes file. It could be possible that another route is matching instead due to ordering, grouping, etc.

Comment: I emptied everything else in the routes file, and confirmed that there's no _method field in the data. Still a 405.

Comment: I can take a -1 like a big boy, but would someone care to explain why?

Comment: mav , how your live and local url looks like ?

Comment: @C2486 my local URL is just `localhost` and my live URL is `https://example.com/the-path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the data that I was sending. I'm not sure why, but my server didn't like the entire projects array, so I updated it to send just an array of the `id`s I'd like to delete, and consequently updated the controller to just `destroy` the request. If someone has an explanation, I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the csrf token

Update your ajax post data as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/dashboard/delete-projects',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        projectsToDelete: JSON.stringify(vThis.selectedProjects),
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
    },
    complete: function(){
        vThis.refreshProjects();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd previously globally set the csrf token. Apologies for not mentioning that.

Comment: Another common issue I have faced is the route can be caught before arriving the route you have defined. Put the route definition of the ajax at the top of routes list

Comment: A missing CSRF token would not result in a 405 error.

Comment: @Devon I solved it by changing the form data to send a single linear array. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A 405 error in Laravel means the route does not exist for the HTTP method you are using.

If you are receiving this error on production but not locally, it would indicate your route files are either outdated or have been cached.

Clear your route cache with:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Verify your POST route exists with:

```
php artisan route:list --path=ajax/dashboard/delete-projects
```

If route:list confirms your POST route exists but you're still receiving a 405, the other thing that can lead to cached routes is opcache without revalidating timestamps, in which you may need to restart your php processes to clear.

Comment: Tried all of those, still getting the 405.

Comment: Post your route list output and your opcache settings then.  Did you restart your php processes to clear opcache?